# Hide Class in AOT

Tags: axapta, x++, aot

How to hide the user created class in AOT.

I want to hide my class where the source should not be visible. I know how to do this in form and table. Please guide me how to do the same for class.

Comment: It's not the same thing but can you not create a security key for this to prevent users from executing/calling the class?  Example: hasSecuritykeyAccess(securitykeynum(CreditCardSetup),AccessType::Edit)
A curious question ;)

Comment: who do you want to hide it from? sounds like you need a security audit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but it not possible to hide the source, if you have the credentials to see the AOT.

It is not possible to do for forms and tables either. Please tell us how you do that :)